# After installation of SharePoint server service pack 1, About me link has changed to sort:?

Tags: sharepoint-server

For configuration of One drive in SharePoint On-premise, i have installed SharePoint server 2013 service pack 1 in my server. Now the "Sites" in Suite delegate bar is not visible and About me link was changed to Sort:

[image]

I have followed the steps from this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2014/07/06/sharepoint-2013-configure-on-premises-users-to-leverage-office-365-for-their-mysite-onedrive-part-4.aspx

Please guide me to solve this issue. I am new to SharePoint. So, please tell me whether i did right or wrong!

Comment: did you run the configuration wizard after the Service Pack installation? which SP1 you installed( their are two version, one is faulty and 2nd is good)?

Comment: Yes i run configuration wizard after the installation of service pack 1. I installed this only "officeserversp2013-kb2880552-fullfile-x64-en-us"

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but after SP installation you may need to reprovision User Profile Syncronization service (note: use farm account to start it) and start a full sync after.

Comment: I tried what you said. but same error exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution and my issue is fixed.

1. I just download the coreserverloc2013-kb3039703-fullfile-x64-glb.exe and install in my server.
2. Restart the IIS and Server and my issue is fixed, now its working great.